# Add decimal to last two numbers in numeric string in R

Tags: r

I have a numeric string where I need to add a decimal point before the last 2 numbers.

So,

```
3000
```

Becomes:

```
30.00
```

At first I thought I could use;

```
df$cost <- gsub("[0-9][0-9]$", ".[0-9][0-9]$", df$cost)
```

But that idea definitely doesn't work.

What are my options to solve this problem in R?

Comment: More examples of your input data might be good here - do your data include entries with only 1 or 2 digits like "35" or "6"? That will affect what solutions will work.

Comment: Also `gsub("([0-9][0-9])$", ".\\1", "3000")` is a slight tweak on your original attempt that works OK for your single example.

Comment: @Marius Yes thank you for the question! I do have some data with only 1 and 2 digits, like the examples you provided!

Comment: There's no such thing as a *numeric string*. You either have a numeric (a number that can have math operations applied to it) or a string (a sequence of characters that might be numeric). Convert to an actual number and divide by 100.0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this is too naive, but how about:

```
format(as.numeric("1234") / 100,nsmall = 2)
[1] "12.34"
```

Comment: Awesome thank you!! With 1 tweak this worked perfectly: 

df$cost <- as.numeric(format(as.numeric(df$cost) / 100, nsmall = 2))

Because the dataset imports as chr!